# Annotations in MVC to specify custom input id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, annotations

Is there a way to specify custom id through annotations?

E.g.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Your Name Required")]
[Display(Name = "Your Name")]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[MaxLength(120, ErrorMessage = "Must be under 120 characters")]                
public String Name { get; set; }
```

This is used in a view to generate labels and editor fields. Id of the generated control is set to "Name", which is not unique. I would like to be able to set a custom id. Can this be achieved with annotations?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the ID of a field in your view. Your model shouldn't care about that.

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Name, new { id = "other-id" }) %>
```